# Execute bcp to insert into database

Tags: c#, sql-server, bcp

I have written a C# program to execute `bcp` command and transfer data from `.txt` files into SQL Server tables. When I execute the command using command line it executes fine.

When I run the program shown below it gives this error:

> at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardError()
>   at ...StandardError has not been redirected.

Code:

```
string outputfilename = @"C:\Output.txt";
string cmdExe = "MyDB.dbo.a in outputfilename -c -T -S servername\\DEV -U readonly -P readonly -F2";
 System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
 p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\\";
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "BCP";


 p.StartInfo.Arguments = cmdExe;

 try
 {
     p.Start();
     p.BeginOutputReadLine();

     StreamReader myStreamReader = p.StandardError;
     // Read the standard error of net.exe and write it on to console.
    Console.WriteLine(myStreamReader.ReadLine());
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace.ToString());
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     Console.ReadLine();
 }
 if (p.WaitForExit(100))
 {
     // Process completed. Check process.ExitCode here.
     p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

add:

```
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

This is required if you want to access `p.StandardError` later in the code.

Comment: thanks!! that solved the error. Now my program runs for about 30 seconds but nothing is written to the tables. How can I debug this??